# Access array by string key x, where x is "123"

Tags: php, arrays

We have an array of which the keys are Strings, but those strings sometimes just are numbers (e.g. "123"). When trying to access the array by the key "123", we get an Undefined Index notice. When accessing it by just the integer 123, we get the Undefined Offset notice. This tells us we're trying to index it correctly using the "123" string, but it's still not set.

Trying to come up with an example for this SO question this is hard, since PHP converts array keys in our test case to integers automatically, while in our real-world application this does not happen (due to use of a Java Bridge). The test array we're trying now is:

```
<?php
$array = array("123" => array(108, 8));
var_dump($array);
?>
```

This returns:

```
array(1) { [123]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(108) [1]=> int(8) } }
```

While in our real-world equivalent, it would return:

```
array(1) { ["123"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(108) [1]=> int(8) } }
```

So in the real world the index actually is a String:

```
<?php
var_dump(array_keys($array));
?>
```

returns

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "123" }
```

So, finally the question is the output of the following code:

```
<?php
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (!isset($array[$key])) {
        print "What is happening here?";
    }
} 
?>
```

which gives:

```
What is happening here?
```

Based on Yoshi's comment, here's working test code:

```
<?php
$array = (array)json_decode('{"123":[108,8]}');
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (!isset($array[$key])) {
        print "What is happening here?";
    } else {
        print "Nothing to see here, move along";
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: Can't help you on the answer for your question. But if you use `$array = (array)json_decode('{"123":[108,8]}');` You'll get your realworld example (having `123` as a string key). Maybe this will help others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: (reference) http://codepad.org/ewMJyKDU   I think this is a really interesting question. And hopefully someone can share some light on the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very elegant solution too, but also works and do not require recreating array. Also, you can access the element value.

```
$array = (array)json_decode('{"123":100}');
$array_keys = array_keys($array);
$array = (object)$array;

foreach ($array_keys as $key)
{

    if (!isset($array->$key))
    {
        print "What is happening here?";
    }
    else {
        print "It's OK val is {$array->$key}";
    }
}
```

Note `$` before key in `$array->$key`, it is important.

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance, just finally got around to check this.
Indeed, it is not very elegant, but it sure does work.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this code (and line `$array[(string)$key]`)

```
<?php
$array = array("123" => array(108, 8));

foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    if (!isset($array[(string)$key]))
    {
        print "What is happening here?";
    }
    else print "It's just types";
}
```

Type of $key was automatically casted to integer, and it's why this key was not found in array.

All information about it you can find in manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

This code will works with both cases:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $array))
    {
        print "What is happening here?";
    }
    else print "It's just types";
}
```

Comment: Try using `$array = (array)json_decode('{"123":[108,8]}');`. It will print `What is happening here?`.

Comment: @Yoshi have you tried? It outputs "It's just types". And json_decode has second argument to return array.

Comment: We've tried. It outputs "What's happening here?". We've updated the question with the test-code we used.

Comment: @OZ_ I wasn't trying to falsify your answer. I just wanted to help the OP clearify his problem/question.

Comment: @drvdijk My code (in answer) is different, and this difference is answer to your question. And my code returns "It's just types" for this case.

Comment: @OZ_ Noticed. But in our real-world case, we can't use the array-construction you did, because we get the array from a Java bridge. Thanks though!

Comment: @drvdijk from Java bridge you have key as integer or as string? Cast type of key to int if your key is integer, otherwise to string.

Comment: The key is a string, which might sometimes be a integer (e.g. "123"), but might as well be an ordinary string. Converting it to one or the other is not really an option...

Comment: @drvdijk then just replace `!isset(` with `empty(` - it will work correct and without warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (but with array_intersect_key).

Here is my solution:

```
$array = array_combine(array_keys($array), $array)
```